# Flutter: Icon in TextButton doesn't recenter when I change button's height

Tags: flutter, button, widget, icons

I'm trying to create a `TextButton` that contains an `Icon` and a `Label` like this:

[image: Taken off my app's design on Figma]

But every time I try to reduce the button´s `height` property, it centers the label but not the icon.
[image: The actual result from the app]

I'm achieving this with a `TextButton` (wrapped with a `SizedBox` with a 28px `width`), that has a `Row` as its child, that contains an `Icon` and a `TextWidget`.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 28,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: Icon(
                hasIcon ? icon : null,
                size: 18,
              ),
            ),
            content is String
                ? Text(
                    (content as String).toUpperCase(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 8, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  )
                : content,
          ],
        ),
(...)
```

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

in the TextButton child Row, you can add the **mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center**
This will center horizontally the row's elements.

Comment: Does not work. Stays exactly the same.